# Resolver essa questão de banco de dados

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

eu deduzi em fazer assim, porém eu acredito que com isso eu só tenho a informação de quem não comercializou, poderiam me dar uma luz nessa questão?

SELECT CR.nome
FROM corretor as CR
Inner JOIN comercialização as C
on CR.matricula = C.matriculaCorretor
WHERE C.matriculaCorretor is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com `INNER JOIN` você só recupera o que existe nas duas tabelas, ou seja só os que realizaram alguma comercialização.

No seu caso utilize `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT CR.nome, (CASE WHEN C.matriculaCorretor IS NULL THEN 'Não' ELSE 'Sim' END) AS status
FROM corretor as CR
LEFT OUTER JOIN comercialização as C
ON CR.matricula = C.matriculaCorretor;
```

Todos os corretores com a indicação se realizaram ou não comercialização.